# App Sandbox not enabled on helper app, error uploading to Apple

Tags: macos, app-store, entitlements

I have an app that is currently in the Mac App Store. It consists of the main app, and a loadable bundle in the PlugIns folder (/Contents/PlugIns) as well as a Luncher helper under login items (/Contents/Library/LoginItems/)

With Xcode 12.4 I am able to build but when I try to upload it to Apple I get a error:

```
ERROR ITMS-90296: "App sandbox not enabled. The following executables must include the
"com.apple.security.app-sandbox" entitlement with a Boolean value of true in the
entitlements property list:[("com.mycompany.myapp.mas.pkg/Payload/MyApp.app/
Contents/Library/LoginItems/MyApp Launcher.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp Launcher")]

Refer to App Sandbox page at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/app_sandbox
for more information on sandboxing your app."
```

The sandbox IS enabled for the Launcher. I am using the same entitlements file for all three code parts (app, loadable bundle and helper).

The helper has its own bundle identifier but no provisioning profile because the bundle id is not registered in my "Certificates, Identifiers and Profiles" as it is not an independent app for distribution by itself.

This is very frustrating as it worked in Xcode 11 but does not work in Xcode 12.

```
codesign --verify --deep --verbose /mainapp.app/

valid on disk
satisfies its Designated Requirement
```

And checking entitlements on the helper:

```
codesign -d --entitlements :- /mainapp.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems/helper.app

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.bookmarks.app-scope</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.absolute-path.read-only</key>
    <array>
        <string>/</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.mach-lookup.global-name</key>
    <array>
        <string>com.apple.testmanagerd</string>
        <string>com.apple.coresymbolicationd</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Hi, have you find any solution to this issue? I am also suffering from this issue. It's so weird that I do have the entitlement in the project, but it keep telling me that sandbox not enabled.

Comment: I fixed it but not sure how exactly as I ended up rebuilding my project which took about a day. I'll see if I have any notes about it but I didn't get much to go on from DTS.

Comment: Looks like when the pkg is built with command line tool, need to specify the entitlement file. If you make the binary from xcode, then it will not has such issue.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you've gotten this resolved but you can get past this by explicitly specifying the entitlements file in the IDE as well.  On Visual Studio for Mac you need to have the application bundle signing / provisioning profile selected.  Once that is the case you will see that the area where you specify the entitlements.plist file is now enabled (meaning it will now be used)